# Cloud Functions for Firebase - subscribe a user to a topic

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi there I want to subscribe a user to a specific topic using Cloud Functions for Firebase in a Node.js environment, I've followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNR9El3XWYo, where a Firebase expert shows how to subscribe a user when a write to a node in Firebase is made, here´s my complete code:

```
//For subscriptions
exports.privateEventSubs = functions.database.ref("Events/{eventID}/guest_mod/assistants/{guestEmail}").onWrite((event) => {
    let data = event.data;
    let eventID = data.ref.parent.parent.parent.key;
    console.log("The eventID is: " + eventID);
    let guestEmail = data.ref.key;
    console.log("The guestEmail is: " + guestEmail);

    //Add or remove a subscription
    let action = data.exists() ? "batchAdd" : "batchRemove";
    console.log("The action is: " + action);


    //Get the device token from each user
    admin.database().ref("Users/" + guestEmail + "/chat_data/firebaseToken").once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log("The user token is: " + snapshot.val());

        //Send messages to users that have subscribed to that event
        functions.config().firebase.credential.getAccessToken().then(function (oauthToken) {
            console.log("The oauthToken is: " + oauthToken.access_token);
            //Lets configure and request
            request({
                url: "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:" + action, //URL to hit
                method: 'POST',
                json: true,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + oauthToken.access_token,
                    access_token_auth: true,
                },
                body: {
                    to: "/Events/" + eventID,
                    registration_tokens: snapshot.val()
                }
            }, function (err, res, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(res.statusCode, body);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The error I get is this one:

```
   400 { error: 'InvalidListOfTokens' }
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help! :(

Comment: the question and the error has been updated!

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like you are passing a single value in for the `registration_tokens` key. According to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server) this should be an array.

So changing `registration_tokens: snapshot.val()` to `registration_tokens: [snapshot.val()]` should put the request in the format the API expects.